# Synchronous HttpWebRequest wait for redirections to be completed

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm using `HttpWebRequest` to request information from a webpage however sometimes the website redirects me around until I get to the correct page, which is totally fine, however when I use the code bellow the content string (`string content`) which should contain the end page content (after redirecting), actually contains the redirection page saying "Redirecting".

Basically I need to make the following request wait for all redirections to be completed before getting the response. How do I do that?

```
HttpWebRequest http = HttpWebRequest.Create(loginUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
http.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
// Wait for redirections to be completed before getting response
....
using (var response = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (content.Length > 0)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

After examining the redirection page, I could tell the redirection is performed via Javascript which my be throwing off HttpWebRequest redirection logic. Suggestions to account for this, or should I try another thing, maybe another .Net wrapper for these proceedings?

Comment: This should work. If what you are saying is true this is a bug in HttpWebRequest. Unlikely. Use Fiddler to capture those requests and make sure that the response body is really what you expect.

Comment: @usr It might not be a bug in HttpWebRequest. From the HTML in the redirection page that I grabbed from the content string. I could tell the redirection is performed with Javascript, that might be throwing off HttpWebRequest redirection logic.

Comment: Technically, that's not a redirect. HttpWebRequest has no bug, then. It is not supposed to support JavaScript redirects. It does not even know what JS is.

Comment: Yes after seeing the redirection was performed through Javascript, I checked the documentation and it's clear HttpWebRequest does not contain any Javascript engine. People with my problem should consider using WebBrowser control for example, or instead follow the idea suggested in the answer and parse the Javascript. I went with the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpWebRequest looks for a redirect status code when you have "auto-redirect" enabled. In this case, the redirect is performed via javascript and the status code is a 200 OK, so you need extra logic to account for this.

There are several options here, the easier way to do this is to parse the response HTML and find the URL to where the script will redirect you. If the script uses information from cookies and such to build the URL, you may need to interpret the javascript on that response to follow the redirect.